# No value for key [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource] error on Java spring API

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, threadpool, connection-pooling

As of recently, my API has been producing the following error when requesting a PUT from a web application. It happens only on PUT for some strange reason. Sometimes it works (spam clicking the item that runs this PUT request) and other times it fails with the error below.

I'm currently running the following java connector and combo pool dependencies:

**mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.48** | **c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2**

I have tried upgrading these to a later version, with the same error being reproduced. Along with this, my JDBC params are as follows:

**noAccessToProcedureBodies=true&useLocalSessionState=true&useLocalTransactionState=false&allowMultiQueries=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false**

The combo pool has the following configuration:

```
 newDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(5);
 newDataSource.setMinPoolSize(3);
 newDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(20);
 newDataSource.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(true);
 newDataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(300);
 newDataSource.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(240);
```

Here's the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTest

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:210) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..framework.core.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:235) ~[classes!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1016) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:811) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:483) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:290) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..service.MessageServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e39f5bf7.updateDomainMessage(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..service.MessageService$updateDomainMessage$0.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

 09:13:49
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-all-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]

 09:13:49
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-all-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]

 09:13:49
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) ~[groovy-all-2.4.7.jar!/:2.4.7]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..resource.MessageController.updateDomainMessage(MessageController.groovy:124) ~[classes!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

 09:13:49
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

 09:13:49
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

 09:13:49
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225) [websocket-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:240) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.1.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..framework.core.DownloadFilter.doFilter(DownloadFilter.java:92) [classes!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..framework.core.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:113) [classes!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..framework.core.RefreshTokenFilter.doFilter(RefreshTokenFilter.java:66) [classes!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at com.agrawal..framework.core.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:56) [classes!/:na]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [jetty-security-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) [jetty-servlet-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253) [jetty-server-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:202) [jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [jetty-io-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [jetty-util-9.3.11.v20160721.jar!/:9.3.11.v20160721]

 09:13:49
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by fixing the call that triggered the transaction. It was accidentally coded to drop the transaction before it was finished.